# What is $\mathbb{P}(X<a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=a)$ given a CDF?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have the following cdf of a random variable $X$.

$$
 F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x < 0; \\
       x/2  & \text{if } 0 \leq  x < 1; \\
       2/3 & \text{if } 1 \leq  x < 2; \\
       11/12  & \text{if } 2 \leq  x < 3; \\
       1      &      \text{if } x \geq 3.\end{cases}
$$

First, what is $\mathbb{P}(X<3)$? Is it $\frac{11}{12}$?
Second, what is $\mathbb{P}(X=1)$? Is it $\frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: CDFs are right-continuous functions.  Thus, $F(a) = P\{X \leq a\}$ is the limiting value of $F(x)$ as $x \to a$ from the right while $P\{X < a\}$ is the limiting value of $F(x)$ s $x \to a$ from the left. The limits are different if there is a jump discontinuity at $a$, and the difference (if any) is the probability that $X = a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x)$ is right-continuous, i.e. $F(x) = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F(x+\epsilon)$, we have:
$$
    \mathbb{P}(X=x) = F(x) - \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F(x-\epsilon)
$$
and
$$
   \mathbb{P}(X<x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x) - \mathbb{P}(X=x) = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F(x-\epsilon)
$$

Numerical values you computed are correct:
$$
    \mathbb{P}(X < 3) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F(3-\epsilon) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{11}{12} = \frac{11}{12}
$$
$$
    \mathbb{P}(X = 1) = F(1) - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} F(1-\epsilon) = \frac{2}{3} - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1-\epsilon}{2} = \frac{1}{6}
$$